# How to implement a TPanel.OnEndResize event-handler?

Tags: delphi, event-handling, resize, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit VCLApplication, I RESIZE a `TPanel` (`align = alClient`) by moving a `TSplitter` control with the mouse. However, the Panel could also be resized by other actions. In this scenario, I need an automatic action to be taken ONCE AFTER the resizing of the Panel has occurred. So I wrote this `OnResize` action:

```
procedure TForm1.TPanel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CodeSite.Send('TForm1.TPanel1Resize: ');
end;
```

However, this `OnResize` event-handler randomly is called **once or twice**! So I need a `TPanel.OnEndResize` event that occurs only once. Also, a `TPanel.OnStartResize` event would be useful. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In general, in situations like these, the guarantee is that the event is called *at least* once, and you are required to handle the scenario when it is called more than once. I can think of a few situations where it is actually very difficult even for a human to determine if the resizing is really finished or not.

Comment: However, there is a trick to implement a `TForm.OnEndResize` event handler using MESSAGES (`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`). So I hoped a similar trick using messages would help me to implement at least e.g. a  `TWinControl.OnEndResize` event handler?

Comment: You could use a timer triggered from OnResize event with an interval of something like 500mS. A rapid successions of OnResize event will prevent the timer to trigger his OnTimer event. 500mS after the last OnResize, the time will finally trigger. You can consider this as the OnEndResize event. Of course, you adjust the 500mS to fit your needs.

Comment: In a simple test I made (with Delphi XE7), I never got a `TPanel.OnResize` more than **once per actual resizing**. On the other hand, using the `TSplitter.OnMove` event, it triggers twice, because in `TSplitter.MouseUp` it calls both `UpdateControlSize` and `StopSizing`. Both of these calls `FOnMoved(self);`

Comment: Perhaps a `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` on the `TSplitter` could act as the resize start and end signal, respecively. They are however not published so you have to make an interposer class. For the *resized by other actions* I have no suggestions as you did not specify what the actions are.

Comment: I would vote for the Timer solution  as is does not require extensive knowledge of why and how the panel was resized...